# Pentaho treating empty string as null

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hello i'm particularly new to pentaho and why when the table_input has an empty string, and when do insert to table_output the data becoming null

for example in the table input

```
ID|name
1|dan
2|
3|itzy
4|kim
5|(null)
```

i do preview my query, and it's ok and has empty string

but when it enter the table output it became null,
i check in the db `SELECT * FROM TABLE_OUTPUT`

```
ID|name
1|dan
2|(null)
3|itzy
4|kim
5|(null)
```

My step consists of `TABLE_INPUT=>TABLE_OUTPUT`
just a simple select and insert
i'm using pdi-ce-9.1.0.0-324

table input is from MYSQL DB, table output is POSTGRESQL 13

Answer (score 2):

you need a setting in kettle.properties. The file is in .kettle in your user dir if you use pdi standalone.

KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL = Y

BR Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is beyond Pentaho the problem you have, for as you see, It makes no change in the data at all, it only reads and write it. I tried various steps, trying to replace the empty string with a space or a tab, but didn't manage it.
You will have to run the following code in your SQL:

*SELECT ISNULL( name , '')*

or

*SELECT COALESCE( name , '')*

This way, you'll be able to work with your DB if there comes a task that doesn't allow null values.

(you can use the **'SQL Script'** step in Pentaho and run this after populating the table)

I hope I did help you!
Have a good day!